# How to get only selected checkboxes in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `ng-repeat`ed data, and am trying to get only the ones the user has selected. I'm not sure how to do it though, this is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="record in records">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="record.Id"> {{record.Id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="ShowSelected()">Show Selected</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) 
{
    $scope.records = [ { "Id": 1 }, { "Id": 2 }, { "Id": 3 } ];
    $scope.ShowSelected = function() 
    {
        // how can I get only the selected records here ?
    }
}
```

I did get it working one way - by adding a `isSelected:false` property to each object and changing the `ng-model` of the checkbox to `record.isSelected`, I can then filter on that in the `ShowSelected` function. This seems inefficient though, I don't want to be adding extra properties to the model if can avoid it.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [ { "Id": 1 }, { "Id": 2 }, { "Id": 3 } ];
    $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.ShowSelected = function() {
      $scope.records = $.grep($scope.records, function( record ) {
        return $scope.selected[ record.Id ];
      });
    };      
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="record in records">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[record.Id]"> {{record.Id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="ShowSelected()">Show Selected</a>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lqtDQ6

You can store the flag in separately and use it to filter the data.

## updated plunk as some CDN links were broken.

Comment: lining to only an offsite resource that doesn't seem to work right anymore is not great...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way would be to add property 'isSelected' to your record and bind to that value. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="record.isSelected">
```

another thing you can do (specially if you 'cannot' add that extra property to the record, would be to maintain an array of selected items and add/remove them from the selected array when the user makes the selection:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="recordSelected(result)" ng-true-value="{{record.id}}" ng-false-value="{{-record.id}}" ng-model="result">
```

The recordSelected function will be handled in your controller to add/remove and record from the selected records list.

PS: I used a negative record id to represent the record was unselected.