# how to check multiple checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sportId" ng-required="!sportId" data-checklist-model="player.sport_id" data-checklist-value="role.id" ng-click="myFunction(role.id)" ng-change="stateChanged(player.sport_id)">

    $scope.roles = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Hockey'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Soccer'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Lacrosse'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Golf'},
    {id: 5, text: 'Football'},
    {id: 6, text: 'Other'}
  ];
```

i have used this method it works good bt it work for single checkbox if you i select multiple checkbox it doesn't check correctly

reason why because when i click one checkbox it has none value in array when i unchecked it has first id. So in the other end if i select 1st (none value in array hence response correct) if i click and select 2nd id (it has one 2 value true) then it says uncheck

how to check multiple checkbox is checked

```
$scope.stateChanged = function(changedSport){

        if($scope.player.sport_id == false)
        {
          alert("Checked");

        }else{
          alert("unChecked");


   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only selected checkboxes in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579986/how-to-get-only-selected-checkboxes-in-angularjs)

Comment: We only see one checkbox in your snippet.  If you want us to help with multiple checkboxes, post the entire snippet of code that you need help with.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nn2p83p8/

Comment: you need to add https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/checklist-model/0.9.0/checklist-model.js