# How to get the values of multiple checkboxes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I got 7 checkboxes. I want to get the value of the selected checkbox and store into an object. Ff it is deselected I want to remove it in the object.

**HTML**

```
<span ng-repeat="days in selectDays">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{days}}" ng-model="daysSelected"/>
    <label for="{{days}}">{{days}}</label>
</span>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.selectDays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
$scope.selectedList = {}; //this is the object to store the selected checkbox values
```

Comment: [How to get only selected checkboxes in angularjs?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12579986)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only selected checkboxes in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579986/how-to-get-only-selected-checkboxes-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code is a simple approach -> check this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/I8tgqn5bPO2gzxmlWL6W/). This example delivers you a very simple [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) handling for mulitple autogenerated checkboxes in AngularJS.

#### Template

```
<span ng-repeat="day in selectDays">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{day}}" ng-model="selectedList[day]"/>
    <label for="{{day}}">{{day}}</label>
</span>
<button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

#### Scopes

```
//default states
$scope.selectDays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
$scope.selectedList = {};

/**
 * Action
 */
$scope.submit = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedList, function (selected, day) {
        if (selected) {
           console.log(day);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Great +1, but its helpful to avoid using `console` in you plunker, try adding:
`<p>{{selectedList|json}}</p>` to your plunker.

Comment: You also need to check "selected" variable in the loop. It will get listed if you once checked and un-check the same value.

Comment: Thanks @lin, Very simple and easy to understand.

Comment: How can check the checkbox automatically ? eg. If i will get the data "SUN" from backend then i have to check the "Sun" checkbox. if i will get multiple data like "SUN, MON", then i need to check the respective checkboxes automatically. In this case how to do this ?

Comment: @Kishan open a new question please.

Comment: how to remove the uncheck day to the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.checkFun= function(data) {


                    for(var i in data){                                                                              
                       if(data[i].SELECTED=='Y'){ 
                          $scope.selectedList.push(data[i]);  
                         }
                        if(data[i].SELECTED=='N'){  
                          $scope.selectedList.splice(data[i]);
                         }
    }

<input type="checkbox" id="{{days}}" ng-model="selectDays.SELECTED" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'" ng-click="checkFun(selectDays)">
```

Comment: The answer is not simple as the question.

Comment: @FaouziOudouh did i missed any thing ?

Comment: Nothing but your answer added unwanted complexity the job.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1aurav/026mc5c6/1/), it uses ngChange directive from angular whenever the checkbox is clicked a function is called. The code looks something like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<span ng-repeat="day in selectDays">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{day}}" ng-model="daysSelected" ng-change= "change(day)"/>
    <label for="{{day}}">{{day}}</label>
</span>
<span ng-repeat="day in selectedList">
<div>
{{day}}
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.selectDays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
$scope.selectedList = []; 
$scope.change = function(day) {
var indexOfDay = $scope.selectedList.indexOf(day); 
    if(indexOfDay === -1) {
        $scope.selectedList.push(day)
    } else {
        $scope.selectedList.splice(indexOfDay, 1)
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: How can check the checkbox automatically ? eg. If i will get the data "SUN" from backend then i have to check the "Sun" checkbox. if i will get multiple data like "SUN, MON", then i need to check the respective checkboxes automatically. In this case how to do this ?