# Using angular get value of selected check box that created by php dynamically

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to get check box value that was created dynamically, I have searched about this but I didn't get any solution

```
<div ng-app="formListApp" ng-controller="formListController">
<form action="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <button class="md-raised" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="applyTemplate()">Allpy Template</button>
    <table>
        <tr id="header" class="header_row_hed">
            <td id="sl_no" class="sl_no_col_hed">Sl.No</td>
            <td id="chk_box" class="chk_box_col_hed">
                <input name="select_all" id="selectAll" class="" style="" ng-model="all" type="checkbox">
                Select All
            </td>
            <td id="form_name" class="form_name_col_hed">Form Name</td>
            <td id="template_name" class="template_name_col_hed">Applied template</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
          $slNo = 1;
          foreach ( $form_list as $form_lists ) {

            <tr id="form-<?php echo $form_lists['id']; ?>" class="header_row">
                <td id="<?php echo $slNo; ?>" class="sl_no_col"><?php echo $slNo; ?></td>
                <td id="chk-box-<?php echo $form_lists['id']; ?>" class="sl_no_col_hed">
                    <input name="select_all" id="selectAll-<?php echo $form_lists['id']; ?>" class="" style=""
                           ng-checked="all" ng-model="formId<?php echo $slNo; ?>" type="checkbox"
                           val="<?php echo $form_lists['id']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td id="form-id-<?php echo $form_lists['id']; ?>"
                    class="form_name_col"><?php echo $form_lists['name']; ?></td>
                <td class="template_name_col"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
</div>

<script>
var myAdminApp = angular.module('formListApp');

myAdminApp.controller('formListController', function AdminController($scope) {
    $scope.formId = {};

    $scope.applyTemplate = function () {

    }
});
</script>
```

this is my code I'm new to angular is it possible to get check box value?

Comment: refer to this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579986/how-to-get-only-selected-checkboxes-in-angularjs

Comment: i am using database to fetch value for check box, i cant store value in anguler

Comment: ng-model is used to store the value in angular. in your code your storing the ng-model with "formId<?php echo $slNo; ?>".  other wise you have to fetch the checkbox value with the help of id. ex: document.getElementById('#id').checked

Comment: that is javasript, it means using ng-model it was not possible? anyway thanks for solution.

Comment: using ng-model u have to assign the ng-modal with data instead of id. then u can fetch the value.